# How to achieve fun[Unevaluated[f][Unevaluated[x], Unevaluated[y]] in a more elegant way?

Tags: evaluation, hold

I have defined a function `fun[f_[x_,y_]]`. When I call it, I want to wrap everything by `Unevaluated`:

```
fun[Unevaluated[f][Unevaluated[x], Unevaluated[y]]
```

But the above expression looks clumsy, especially if the arguments of `fun` is more complicated. Is there a more elegant way to do it?

A simple example of the function `fun` is as follows. The last line is what I expect to get.

```
fun[f_[x_, y_]] := ToExpression[ToString[f] <> ToString[x] <> ToString[y]]
f = 1; x = 1; y = 1;
fun[f[x, y]]
(* -> 111 *)
fun[Unevaluated[f][Unevaluated[x], Unevaluated[y]]
(* -> fxy *)
```

I tried several ways by using a single `Unevaluated` or `HoldPattern`, and they do not work.

Comment: Have you tried giving `fun` the `HoldAll` attribute?

Comment: I just tried, and it does not work.

Comment: @renphysics Why? `SetAttributes[fun, HoldAll]; 
fun[f_[x_, y_]] := Unevaluated[f][Unevaluated[x], Unevaluated[y]]; 
f = x = y = 1; 
fun[f[x, y]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you want:

```
SetAttributes[fun, HoldAll];
fun[expr_] := Identity @@ Identity @@ 
 MapAll[Unevaluated, Hold[expr], Heads -> True]
```

The two `Identity` operations fix the fact that `MapAll` applies `Unevaluated` to the entire expression as well - `MapAll[g, f[x,y]]` is `g[g[f][g[x],g[y]]` when we want `g[f][g[x],g[y]` - and remove the `Hold` we artificially put in.

Comment: +1 for the use of MapAll!